# Is my webcam hacked?

Tags: linux, networking, camera, malware

Linux (ubuntu) user here. I have been using Linux for a long time, which makes me comfortable with the command line. So, I am looking for suggestions and tools to help me solve this problem. **In case this is not the right platform to ask for help, please point me in the right direction.**

> How do I know that my webcam is hacked?

- Often, when I start my browser, the indicator light is on for a while (often on chrome).
- Often, when I do the right click with the mouse, the indicator light is on for a while.
- Whenever I reboot my system, the indicator light is on for a while (3-4 seconds).
- During a video chat with someone, I noticed strange behavior. The indicator will go off a while and then come back; it happened multiple times.

What is the first step in getting rid of that malicious software?

Comment: Point 3 is normal. When the system enumerates devices and then load the appropriate drivers.

Comment: [Your question on the Security SE site](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/263108/webcam-hacked-help-needed) was closed with the comment "None of what you have described indicates malware."

Comment: You can see who has the webcam open with `sudo lsof /dev/video0` (ise your device name, if it's not `dev/video0`). OR temporarily `chmod 000 /dev/video0` and see what fails.

Comment: it makes no sense to hack a camera ... it is easier to hack the computer that it is connected to

Answer (score 0):

As the first you can check output of `dmesg` command, maybe your camera is only reconnecting due to hardware failure. 
 If it's possible, try to change cable. If you use any USB hub, try your camera connect directly to USB port.
You can scan your computer with `rkhunter, clamav` and `lynis`.

Comment: Of course neither rkhunter nor clamav nor lynis will "scan your device"

Comment: Oh, small typo ... Edited: Device -> Computer!